# Group by PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I have the following result

```
Student Form ID  | Result
-----------------------------
12               | PASSED
131              | PASSED
131              | RESIT
144              | FAIL
23               | NA
```

Ideally I want where the ID is the same eg 131. To group the results so ID         Result

```
Student Form ID  | Result
--------------------------------
131              | PASSED, RESIT
```

When I use group by, it isn't giving me the desired output, I'm obviously doing it wrong. Please could I have some guidance on how to achieve my desired result, i.e. where the ID is the same, the results should be grouped on one row.

Comment: Try using `string_agg` or `array_agg` to aggregate the results.

Comment: `SELECT id, STRING_AGG(result, ', ') AS result FROM your_table GROUP BY id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation is PostgreSQL: array_agg() or json_agg()

```
select student_form_id, array_agg(result) from your_table group by student_form_id;
```

Comment: Correct but why mention json_agg, there is no json in this question.

Comment: It's safe to use json_agg() in my opinion. Output can be processed easily.

Comment: Mavis is clearly looking for `string_agg()`

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the help, string_agg worked perfectly. Thanks again :)